# Scaling Graphics (Beginning Java Programmer)

Tags: java, graphics, scaling

I am Chris.
I am fairly new to coding, I don't know many terms, this is my third and most successful attempt at learning Java. Yeah, It didn't work out so much was I was younger.
Anyhow, I am trying to create a game but I'm having a slight problem.

I made a 16 x 16 image as my character, however - as expected- it shows up as fairly small.
[image: This is what it looks like]

I have absolutely no clue how to make it larger.

Here is the code:

```
package code;

import java.awt.Graphics;


public class Skeleton extends Loop{ //Should extend Applet?

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void init(){
Thread th= new Thread(this);
th.start();
offscreen = createImage(120,160); // 120, 160
d = offscreen.getGraphics();
addKeyListener(this); //15:43
}
public static final int HEIGHT = 120; //Original Height/Width= "120 x 160"
public static final int WIDTH = 160;
public static final String TITLE= "Test Game BETA";
public static final int SCALE = 3;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
d.clearRect(0, 0, 160, 120); //Error Here, Scale perhaps? -Disregard //0, 0, 160, 120
d.drawImage(him, x, y, this);     //12:17 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmRD0PlAXEY
g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
}
public void update(Graphics g){
    paint(g); 

} //Finished at 15:33 ERROR w/ the circle -Fixed
} 
//2D Tile Engine Must be Created
```

Comment: The `drawImage` function can take a destination size, and it will scale your image for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

Comment: THANK YOU. You saved me a lot of time and troubles.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: Put it as an answer @blorgbeard so the question doesn't show as unanswered please - and so the OP can give you rep :)

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) of interest

Comment: Thank you Blorgbeard and MadProgrammer, this has been haunting me forever, oh and Blorgbeard, you might like to take Tim B's advice, your choice though. Thank you everyone and good luck programming.

Comment: Posted as requested! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drawImage function can take a destination size, and it will scale your image for you:

```
drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageObserver observer)
```

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html